# Null Pointer Exception android bitmaps

Tags: java, android

This is my java class. Why am i getting a null pointer? isnt it fine? like ive initialized everything. The error showing is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

```
public class Screenshot extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your fos is null i think

Comment: fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);

How is it null

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is null. As per logs you are trying to access t 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress  method on null object. Hence bitmap is null for sure.

You can try this code as well to get bitmap :

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're requesting a bitmap from a view that has not yet been laid out and drawn, so there is no drawing cache available.  You have to wait for Android to do this for you before you can generate a Bitmap from it.  Use this strategy intead:

- In onCreate, inflate your view and get a reference to the root view.
- Call setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) on the root view.
- With the root view, call [getViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver()) to get a reference to a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html).
- Register a listener on the ViewTreeObserver with [addOnGlobalLayoutListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener)). This listener will be called when layout is finished.
- In your listener implementation, get the drawing cache as you are now.
- You may also want to remove the listener so it won't get called again if there is another layout change

Answer (score -1):

view#getDrawingCache() is the cause of the NPE,

modify the `Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();` for

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(takeScreenshot());
```